# How to remove the 'Archives' title and list and the 'Meta' title

Tags: sidebar

How can I remove the 'Archives widget' and the 'Meta widget' from the pages on my blog -- for example, on this page: http://richardclunan.com/ ?

And how can I remove those from every page but keep them on the blog ?

Comment: you might need to customize the page.php template.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the plugin [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/).  It adds a text field under each widget in the appearance -> widgets menu that lets you add conditional filters.  For example if you wanted a widget to only display on your blog page you would add, `is_home()` to the field under the widget.

[image] Also, check the [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to see all possibilities.